# How do I restart a program using loops in C programming?

Tags: c

I have a code where there are categories and subcategories. I want to ask the person if they want to choose another category and basically do the same thing they just did. What and where can I put some code that will allow them to restart the program without closing it and reopening it again?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  int choice;
  float f, k, celcius, usd, cad, eur, sec, days, hour, value, oz, lbs, kg;
  
  printf("Select a category\n");
  printf("1. Temp\n");
  printf("2. Money\n");
  printf("3. Time\n");
  printf("4. Weight\n\n");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  
  printf("Select a category\n");
  printf("1.Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
  printf("2.Celsius to Kelvin\n");
  printf("3.Fahrenheit to Kelvin\n\n");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  
  if (choice == 1) {
    printf("please enter a number in Celsius: ");
    scanf("%f", &value);
    f = (9 / 5 * value ) + 32;
    printf("the weather in Fahrenheit is: %.2f Fahrenheit\n", f);
  }
  else if (choice == 2){
    printf ("please enter a number in Celsius for Kelvin");
    scanf("%f", &value);
    k = value + 273.15;
    printf("the weather in Kelvin is: %.2f", k);
  }
  else {
    printf ("please enter a number in Fahrenheit");
    scanf("%f", &value);
     k = (value - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15;    
     printf("the weather in kelvin from Fahrenheit is: %.2f", k);
  }
  
  exit(0);
}
```

This is one small part of my program. I basically copy-pasted this a few times but with different categories.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm

Comment: You already mention loops, which is the natural solution for this. What attempts at using loops have you tried? How did they work or not work? Do you have a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part) of any of your attempts?

Comment: Some ideas here: https://www.mikedane.com/programming-languages/c/building-a-guessing-game/

Answer (score 1):

Add another option to exit the program in the menu as ***Enter 5 to exit.***

Then simply put `menu` section of the code in-

```
while(1) {
    if (user_input == 5)
        break;
    // some repeating code here
}
```

And use `switch-case` instead of multiple `if-elses`.
Read about [switch-case here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm)

UPDATE: What I'm trying to say is this-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int user_input = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("----MAIN MENU----\n");
        printf("1. Stuff A\n");
        printf("2. Stuff B\n");
        printf("3. Exit\nEnter the option number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &user_input);
        // removed if-elses and using switch-case
        switch(user_input)
        {
        case 1:
            // code for stuff A
            break;
        case 2:
            // code for stuff B
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Exiting the program...\n");
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("INVALID INPUT. Try again...\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so instead of the if (choice == 1) and if (choice == 2) stuff, I just put while (1) and while (2) for everything??

Comment: @Kryptic-Ninja NO, It's not like that `while(1)` means `while always true`. It means when you put `while(1)`, whatever inside the `while(1)` loop will run infinitely. That's why there's a `break` condition to exit the loop.

Comment: @Kryptic-Ninja Look at the updated answer. Here `while(1)` will run infinitely until user inputs `3`.

Comment: The space in `" %d"` is not needed. Only the `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"` conversion specifiers will read leading whitespace -- all others (including all numeric conversion specifiers) ignore leading whtiespace.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for this comment. But I wanna tell you that this issue with scanning in a loop always driven me nuts. I didn't notice which particular specifier I was using while scanning but after those bad experiences, I always use `" %d"` while scanning inputs in loops. It just ensures me safety.

Comment: No worries and no dings, always worth pointing out because roughly 1/10 questions asked have to do with a misunderstanding of `scanf()`. (that's why `fgets()` is recommended for user-input `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you. I'm learning from people like you. `:)`